# Perl regularexpression match if found print whole line

Tags: regex, perl

I have many lines

```
  Hi i need to work for
  This place
  Which adds me
  More value in this
   wolrd
  Where i can explore my technical skills
```

i am searching for the words adds `me =~ /adds/`

If the match found i have to print the whole line "Which adds me"

How to do this in perl

Comment: These line's in file????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have wondered if one can solve the problem using the option -p. Finally I have found this oneliner

```
perl -pe 'goto LINE unless /adds/;' filename
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -lne 'print if(/\badds\b/)' your_file
```

tested [here](http://ideone.com/K2GMn9)

Comment: What does this function do? @Vijay

Comment: which function are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

With `perl` command:

```
perl -ne '/adds/ && print $_' file
```

**output:**

```
  Which adds me
```

**in script.pl:**

```
while (<>) {
    print if (/adds/);
}
```

then invoke script:

```
perl script.pl file
```

Comment: How to do this without oneliner @vanda

Comment: @user3349964 look @ script version.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (<STDIN>) {
  if($_ =~ m/adds me/) { ##this worked for me
    print $_;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if its in file

```
open(FH,'filename");

while(<FH>){

    if($_=~/adds/){
        print $_;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (<FILE>) {

   if (/adds/) { print $_;}
}
```

Comment: Please explain better your answer